# Finding the kernel of a group involving permutations

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. and let $A=\{xH:x \;in\; G\}$
Assume that $G$ acts on set $A$ by left multiplication .If $F:G$ to Sym $(A)$ is the group homomorphism associated with this $G$ action show that kernel of $F$ is given by the intersections of $xHx^{-1}$ for all $x$ in $G$.

Help please

Comment: I'm guessing $\;H\;$ is a subgroup of $\;G\;$ ...? And what have you done so far?

Comment: Yes H is a subgroup of G. Haven't done much yet. Need help to start the proof

Answer (score 0):

Fill in details

$$g\in\bigcap_{x\in G} xHx^{-1}\implies \forall\,x\in G\;\;\exists\,h_x\in H\;\;\text{such that}\;\;g=xh_xx^{-1}\implies$$

$$g\cdot xH=gxH=xh_xx^{-1}xH=xh_xH=xH\implies g\in\ker F$$

On the other hand

$$g\in\ker F\implies \forall\,x\in G\;,\;\;gxH=xH\implies g\in xHx^{-1}$$

and since the above is true *for all* $\;x\in G\;$ , we have the other direction.

The group $\;\ker F=\bigcap\limits_{x\in G} xHx^{-1}\;$ is called the core of $\;H\;$ .